# how to send django crash report to google docs

Tags: django, crash-reports

i created a django polls app using django docs and i heard there is a way to send Android crash reports to google docs similarly is there any way to send django crash reports to google docs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of storing crash report in google spread sheets is by using [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread). For example lets make a function which will store crash report to a spread sheet. Before that, make a spread sheet and get the url for it.

```
def store_crash_report(request, report):
    gc = gspread.login('yourmail@gmail.com', 'password')
    sht=gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/121...jRRSg')
    #url of spread sheet
    worksheet = sht.get_worksheet(0)
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
      ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
      ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    date_time = str(datetime.now())
    worksheet.insert_row([date_time, ip, report])
```

and use it view like this:

```
def view(request):
   try:
     ...
   exception Exception as e:
      store_crash_report(request, e)
```